# How can I publish a file using Mosquitto in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, file, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using mosquitto c++ wrapper to publish message/file.

In my test I can easily send messages that contain text, but how can I send a file?

My publisher method is:

```
bool Publisher::publish(const char* message) {
    const int ret = mosquittopp::publish(NULL, topic_, strlen(message),
        (uint8_t*) message);
    /* custom log for mosquitto passing res and what I'm doing */
    MosquittoLog::checkResult(ret, "sending message"); 
    return (ret == MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS);
}
```

I find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506939/how-can-i-publish-a-file-using-mosquitto-in-python) where is explained how publish file with python.
Is in c++ almost the same?
If it, how can I distinguish between files and plain text on the Subscriber?

```
void Subscriber::on_message(const struct mosquitto_message* message) {
/* pseudode
   if message is file do A
   else if plainText do B    
*/
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly:

**Publishing a file**

1. Read the file into a memory buffer
2. Pass it, and it's length to publish(...)

*Reading the file*

http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html#read

*Publishing*

What i don't understand from the mosquitto documentation is whether you can destroy the buffer immediately after you publish it, or whether it needs to hang around until the MQTT message is sent.

**Distinguishing between data types**

Either prefix the payload with a flag which describes the data type. Or use a different MQTT topic for different data types.  Failing that, and depending on how space efficient you need to be, you could wrap your payload in a protobuf, JSON or XML message.

Comment: So the distinguishing is against me, checking payload, as you suggest. Ok, this is what I need to know. I was hoping that there was simplest and faster way! Btw thanks!

Comment: in the doubt, I will destroy buffer after the respond!

Comment: Yes.  It's glossed over in the MQTT standard with "Payload: Contains the data for publishing. The content and format of the data is application specific."  See section 3.3: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html

Comment: I'm going to have a look inside mosiqutto and answer that payload question. I need to know anyway :)

Comment: memcpy(message->msg.payload, payload, payloadlen*sizeof(uint8_t)); for QoS != 0.  And looks like it sends straight away for QoS == 0.  So I think you'd be fine to delete your payload immediately on the return from publish.

Comment: I'll try. I've to do hard test, then I report you

Comment: You can free your payload immediately.